# Смена языка на виртуальной клавиатуре

Tags: javascript, клавиатура

Сделала клавиатуру на чистом js.

Как можно реализовать смену языка с англ на рус, и обратно, по нажатию клавиши?

Есть на данный момент такой код, язык меняется, но тогда все кнопки перестают работать.

```
langBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    keyboard.innerHTML = `
    <div class="keyboard-ru">
        <div class="row">
            <button class="btn">1</button>
            <button class="btn">2</button>
            <button class="btn">3</button>
            <button class="btn">4</button>
            <button class="btn">5</button>
            <button class="btn">6</button>
            <button class="btn">7</button>
            <button class="btn">8</button>
            <button class="btn">9</button>
            <button class="btn">0</button>
            <button class="btn">-</button>
            <button class="btn">=</button>
            <button class="btn-backspace">Backspace</button>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <button class="btn">й</button>
            <button class="btn">ц</button>
            <button class="btn">у</button>
            <button class="btn">к</button>
            <button class="btn">е</button>
            <button class="btn">н</button>
            <button class="btn">г</button>
            <button class="btn">ш</button>
            <button class="btn">щ</button>
            <button class="btn">з</button>
            <button class="btn">х</button>
            <button class="btn">ъ</button>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <button class="btn-capslock">CapsLock</button>
            <button class="btn">ф</button>
            <button class="btn">ы</button>
            <button class="btn">в</button>
            <button class="btn">а</button>
            <button class="btn">п</button>
            <button class="btn">р</button>
            <button class="btn">о</button>
            <button class="btn">л</button>
            <button class="btn">д</button>
            <button class="btn">ж</button>
            <button class="btn">э</button>
            <button class="btn-enter">Enter</button>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <button class="btn">я</button>
            <button class="btn">ч</button>
            <button class="btn">с</button>
            <button class="btn">м</button>
            <button class="btn">и</button>
            <button class="btn">т</button>
            <button class="btn">ь</button>
            <button class="btn">б</button>
            <button class="btn">ю</button>
            <button class="btn">/</button>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <button class="btn-lg">Lg</button>
            <button class="btn-space">Space</button>
        </div> 
    </div>
    `
 });
```

Comment: Когда вы меняете innerHTML, то все слушатели событий нужно назначать заново. Лучше сразу сделайте несколько клавиатур (по числу языков) и при смене языка меняйте их видимость.

Comment: Используйте [делегирование событий](https://learn.javascript.ru/event-delegation). Создайте общий элемент для клавиатур и там переключайте раскладку.